# NG-Click not Loading Image AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a simple model with a list of names and corresponding images. I'm trying to click on the name of the image and load the corresponding image.  I can't get the image to load.  The list of names appears on the page, but when I click them nothing happens.  Please help with code.  Thx!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app = "myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Cat Clicker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel ="stylesheet" type "text/css" href ="clicker.css">

    <script type = "text/javascript" src="Libs/angular.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src="js/CatClickerMe.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-controller = "MainController">

  <div ng-repeat = "cat in options.catList">
    <h3 ng-click = "MainController.selectCat($index)">{{cat.name}}</h3>

  <h3>{{MainController.selectedCat.name}}</h3>

  <img ng-src = "{{MainController.selectedCat.images}}" >
  </div>

  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
(function() {

"use strict";


angular.module('myApp',[]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;

$scope.options = {

   catList:[

{
  name:  'Fluffy',
  images: 'images/Fluffy.jpeg'
},
{
  name: 'Tabby',
  images: 'images/tabby.jpeg'
 }
],
};

vm.selectCat=function(pos) {
vm.selectedCat = angular.copy(vm.catList[pos]);
vm.selectedCat.pos = pos;
};

activate();

function activate() {

}

})

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up $ scope and vm, go with one approach. You need to use controller as syntax in the template,

```
<div ng-controller = "MainController as vm">
```

**DEMO**

```js
(function() {

"use strict";


angular.module('myApp',[]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('MainController', function($scope) {
var vm = this;
 vm.selectCat = selectCat;
this.options = {
catList:[
{
  name:  'Fluffy',
  images: 'images/Fluffy.jpeg'
},
{
  name: 'Tabby',
  images: 'images/tabby.jpeg'
 }
],
};

function selectCat(pos) {
vm.selectedCat = pos;
};

})

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app = "myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Cat Clicker</title>
 
<body>

<div ng-controller = "MainController as vm">

  <div ng-repeat = "cat in vm.options.catList">
    <h3 ng-click = "vm.selectCat(cat)">{{cat.name}}</h3>

  <h3>{{vm.selectedCat.name}}</h3>

  <img ng-src = "{{vm.selectedCat.images}}" >
  </div>

  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I changed it all to vm using vm.catList etc.  Now nothing loads on the page.  Do you have an example of how i can make this work?  Thank you.

Comment: do you see the example attached?

Comment: That works!  But it shows two images instead of one.  Is there a way to parse out the repeat, so it doesn't duplicate the images?   Thank you so much!

Comment: Never mind.  I added a </div> tag and that corrected it.  Thank you again!

Comment: One last question. Is there a way to load one initial image[0] or a random image when the page first loads?  This is so the initial image area is not blank.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180557/discussion-between-blake-and-sajeetharan).